# WooCommerce show custom column

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show a additional column in the backend of WooCommerce (in Orders overview).
The column should contain a custom field, which i have defined (delivery date).

How to do this?

Answer (score 38):

In case someone still needs it - instructions on how to add new columns in Woocommerce orders list. No need in unsetting the default columns, just add this in your functions.php and your code will be valid for updates.

## 1. Define columns position and names

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION($columns){
    $new_columns = (is_array($columns)) ? $columns : array();
    unset( $new_columns['order_actions'] );

    //edit this for you column(s)
    //all of your columns will be added before the actions column
    $new_columns['MY_COLUMN_ID_1'] = 'MY_COLUMN_1_TITLE';
    $new_columns['MY_COLUMN_ID_2'] = 'MY_COLUMN_2_TITLE';
    //stop editing

    $new_columns['order_actions'] = $columns['order_actions'];
    return $new_columns;
}
```

## 2. For each custom column, show the values

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION', 2 );
function MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION($column){
    global $post;
    $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

    //start editing, I was saving my fields for the orders as custom post meta
    //if you did the same, follow this code
    if ( $column == 'MY_COLUMN_ID_1' ) {    
        echo (isset($data['MY_COLUMN_1_POST_META_ID']) ? $data['MY_COLUMN_1_POST_META_ID'] : '');
    }
    if ( $column == 'MY_COLUMN_ID_2' ) {    
        echo (isset($data['MY_COLUMN_2_POST_META_ID']) ? $data['MY_COLUMN_2_POST_META_ID'] : '');
    }
    //stop editing
}
```

## 3. (optional) Function to make the columns sortable

```
add_filter( "manage_edit-shop_order_sortable_columns", 'MY_COLUMNS_SORT_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_SORT_FUNCTION( $columns ) {
    $custom = array(
        //start editing

        'MY_COLUMN_ID_1'    => 'MY_COLUMN_1_POST_META_ID',
        'MY_COLUMN_ID_2'    => 'MY_COLUMN_2_POST_META_ID'

        //stop editing
    );
    return wp_parse_args( $custom, $columns );
}
```

Comment: Very well explained answer. Missing a semicolons on the first example

Comment: Do you know if this still works in WooCommerce 2.1.3? I've given it a try but it doesn't seem to work; no custom columns are added. It *seems* like the filter is being applied; if I put `die()` in the function no columns are created, other than that I can't get any change whatsoever.

Comment: @Dre The first filter needs a slightly higher priority other then the default of 10. When I ran it from a plugin making it 11 worked:  `add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION', 11 );`

Comment: Probably not working because WooCommerce have updated & changed their code purposely, to try extort us all by charging $49 for this exact outcome. http://www.woothemes.com/products/admin-custom-order-fields/

Comment: +2 very good answer. Optional step 3 does work fine (running latest WooCommerce)

Comment: My stock column shows quantities. Is there a way to use this code to not only make the stock column sortable, but also sort by stock quantity amount?

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you help with something, I want to show the customer role, how I can add it?

Answer (score 1):

To add new column coupon in woo-commerce order table and get all coupon code according to order. you need to copy and paste in you function.php.

```
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column', 11);

function custom_shop_order_column($columns) {
    //add columns
    $columns['my-column1'] = __('Coupons Code', 'theme_slug');
    return $columns;
}

// adding the data for each orders by column (example)
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'cbsp_credit_details', 10, 2);

function cbsp_credit_details($column) {
    global $post, $woocommerce, $the_order;
    $order_id = $the_order->id;

    switch ($column) {
        case 'my-column1' :
            // $myVarOne = wc_get_order_item_meta( $order_id, 15, true );
            if ($the_order->get_used_coupons()) {

                $coupons_count = count($the_order->get_used_coupons());
                foreach ($the_order->get_used_coupons() as $coupon) {
                    echo $coupon;

                    $i++;
                }

                echo '</p>';
            }
           // echo $myVarOne;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you will get your solution just write below code on your **function.php** file.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns','your_function_name',10 );
function your_function_name($columns){
        $columns['delivery_date'] = __('Delivery date','textdomain');
        return $columns;
    }
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column','your_other_function_name',20 );
function  your_other_function_name($column)
{
    swith($column)
    {
        case 'delivery_date':  // your custom code here and do what you want.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across Woocommerce now. Have added a custom field Personal Registration Number - and now wanted it to be displayed in the Order overview page.

I've manage to add the column - but still couldn't get the value of the custom field for each order.

Here is what I did:

```
// Removed Existing Order Page collumns
remove_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'woocommerce_edit_order_columns');

// Added My own filter to Show the PRN - Personal Registration field
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'omak_edit_order_columns');

// The omak_edit_order_columns definition
/*** Taken from admin/post_types/shop_order.php ***/
function omak_edit_order_columns($columns){
    global $woocommerce;

    $columns = array();

    $columns["cb"]              = "<input type=\"checkbox\" />";
    $columns["order_status"]        = __( 'Status', 'woocommerce' );    
    $columns["order_title"]         = __( 'Order', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns["order_prn"]           = __( 'PRN', 'woocommerce' );    // This is the line which added the column after the Title Column
    $columns["billing_address"]     = __( 'Billing', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns["shipping_address"]    = __( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns["total_cost"]      = __( 'Order Total', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns["order_comments"]  = '<img alt="' . esc_attr__( 'Order Notes', 'woocommerce' ) . '" src="' . $woocommerce->plugin_url() . '/assets/images/order-notes_head.png" class="tips" data-tip="' . __( 'Order Notes', 'woocommerce' ) . '" width="12" height="12" />';

    $columns["note"]                = '<img src="' . $woocommerce->plugin_url() . '/assets/images/note_head.png" alt="' . __( 'Customer Notes', 'woocommerce' ) . '" class="tips" data-tip="' . __( 'Customer Notes', 'woocommerce' ) . '" width="12" height="12" />';

    $columns["order_date"]          = __( 'Date', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns["order_actions"]       = __( 'Actions', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}
```

Let me know if it helps you...

I am left to deal with how to get its values for each Order.

As commented: the function definition exists in shop_order.php in WooCommerce plugin.
Let me know if anybody sorts it out.. or knows how to do it.

Thanks,
(sorry, was busy in something so couldn't read back to check for errors)

Answer (score 0):

The following works for WooCommerce 2.6.2.
You should look into two new hooks:

- [woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers), invoked once when orders table header is generated
- [woocommerce_admin_order_item_values](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_admin_order_item_values/), invoked once per every item inside the order

## 1. Define columns headers

```
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'so13683162_headers');
function so13683162_headers($order) {
    echo "<th>FIELD1</th>";
}
```

## 2. Populate values in rows

```
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'so13683162_values');
function so13683162_values($product) {
    if (isset($product -> id)) {
        $attrs = get_post_meta($product -> id, "_product_attributes", true);
        echo "<td>" . $attrs["FIELD1"]["value"] . "</td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not add the column to the list, it only adds the column to the detail view.