# how can i display product's custom field in wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product ( product listing table in admin ) woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, backend, custom-fields

I have added some custom fields in woocommerce when adding product. Now i want to display those custom fields in product listing page ( wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product ). I also want to quick edit and save like other values can be edit and save in listing page.

I tried bellow code but it did not work.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product', 'show_product_order' );
function show_product_order($columns){
   $new_columns = (is_array($columns)) ? $columns : array();
   unset( $new_columns['order_actions'] );

   $new_columns['product_order'] = 'Product Order';

   $new_columns['order_actions'] = $columns['order_actions'];
   return $new_columns;
}
```

I also tried below code but it did not worked too.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_general_product_data_custom_field' );
function woocommerce_general_product_data_custom_field() {

    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="options_group">';
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
        array(
             'id' => 'product_order',
             'wrapper_class' => 'checkbox_class',
             'label' => __('Order for Product', 'woocommerce' ),
             'description' => __( 'Order for Product', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';
}
```

i also reffered this post [WooCommerce show custom column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683162/woocommerce-show-custom-column) but i did not succeed to get solution
Please help.

Comment: Some how i managed to show custom field on product listing page ( wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product ) by using `add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'show_product_order' );`  But it does not show when i click on Quick edit link. Can anyone tell how can i do this?