# Include a custom field as a Column in Woocommerce Order Overview Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added several custom fields with the "poor guys swiss knife" plugin. I would like to show one (or more) of these in the Order Overview Page of Woocommerce in the Backend of Wordpress as a Column. How can I achieve this?

[Woocommerce Order Overview Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aKk2.png)

From other posts I only found ways to include these fields in the order Detailed page but was unable to find a hook/filter for the overview Table.

Comment: this does the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683162/woocommerce-show-custom-column

Comment: Also see the codex for [`manage_posts_custom_column`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column)