# Display wordpress post_meta into other table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, meta

I've got a question regarding woocommerce and wordpress itself. Probably my issue is dummy yet current code is not working.

What i wanted to achieve is to display my custom field data in the woocommerce orders subpage. My custom field post_meta has name (metakey): **wccpf_authorvalue**

In google i've found some code and just change my post meta name into this one:

```
   add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION($columns){
    $new_columns = (is_array($columns)) ? $columns : array();
    unset( $new_columns['order_actions'] );

    //edit this for you column(s)
    //all of your columns will be added before the actions column
    $new_columns['for-author-value'] = 'Dla autora';
    //stop editing

    $new_columns['order_actions'] = $columns['order_actions'];
    return $new_columns;
}


add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION', 2 );
function MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION($column){
    global $post;
    $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

    //start editing, I was saving my fields for the orders as custom post meta
    //if you did the same, follow this code
    if ( $column == 'for-author-value' ) {    
        echo (isset($data['wccpf_authorvalue']) ? $data['wccpf_authorvalue'] : '');
    }

}


add_filter( "manage_edit-shop_order_sortable_columns", 'MY_COLUMNS_SORT_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_SORT_FUNCTION( $columns ) {
    $custom = array(
        //start editing

        'for-author-value'    => 'wccpf_authorvalue'

        //stop editing
    );
    return wp_parse_args( $custom, $columns );
}
```

The Issue - column is being displayed, yet without any value. Why is that?

I used solution from here: [Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595054/1282022) but it doesnt work.

Comment: Your given code is working fine for me. Have you checked whether `wccpf_authorvalue` is getting saved in database or there is meta with that **key** ?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner - in the DB > _postmeta table I have my record with meta value like ({"type":"text","label":"PLN dla autora","name":"pl..). But there is also table woocommerce_order_itemmeta in which -> each of the orders has got dedicated record to my input (meta value is data which i need). but I dont know how to display it, especially if each order has got own dedicated line.

Comment: Replace `$data = get_post_meta( $post->ID );` with `$data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wccpf_authorvalue', true );` and `echo $data;`. Can you please give me the result after replacing ?

Comment: hey, still nothing. blank value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in fact i've figured out how to solve my issue. Thanks for your support in this matter. If somebody in the future will need a help, im sharing my code below (important, ive decided to add 2 columns)

```
 add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION', 10 );
function MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = ( is_array( $columns ) ) ? $columns : array();
    unset( $new_columns['order_actions'] );
    //edit this for you column(s)
    //all of your columns will be added before the actions column
    $new_columns['product_name'] = 'Product';
    $new_columns['authors_income'] = 'Author';

    $new_columns['order_actions'] = $columns['order_actions'];

    return $new_columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION', 2 );
function MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION( $column ) {
    global $post;
    $order = new WC_Order( $post->ID );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    //start editing, I was saving my fields for the orders as custom post meta
    //if you did the same, follow this code
    if ( $column == 'authors_income' ) {
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {

            echo $item['your field meta key'];
            echo '.00USD';

        }
    }

    if ( $column == 'product_name' ) {
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {

            echo $item['your field meta key'];

        }
    }

}


add_filter( "manage_edit-shop_order_sortable_columns", 'MY_COLUMNS_SORT_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_SORT_FUNCTION( $columns ) {
    $custom = array(
        //start editing

        'authors_income'    => 'your field meta key',
        'product_name'    => 'your field meta key'

        //stop editing
    );
    return wp_parse_args( $custom, $columns );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add priority to the filter so that it can work as you want. Also add this code to the `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION', 11);    

function MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION($columns) {

}
```

Comment: thanks Gaurav unfortunatelly this change doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting key there on MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION. Update the below code. If any issue found please let me know.

`code`
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION',10, 2 );
function MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION($column){
    global $post;
    $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

    //start editing, I was saving my fields for the orders as custom post meta
    //if you did the same, follow this code
    if ( $column == 'for-author-value' ) {    
        echo (isset($data['wccpf_authorvalue']) ? $data['wccpf_authorvalue'] : '');
    }

}

`code`

Comment: You should 

$data = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
print_r($data);

Comment: suggested change didn't help - it has change all data in the ORDERS table into values like: Array ( [_order_key] => Array ( [0] => wc_order_567e99cba6711 )

Answer (score 0):

So What you can do is make it to have a span to display there. like the following

```
<span id="metawrap"></span>
```

And you can update the value using jQuery and Ajax to call a Wordpress Action to get metadata.

Paste the following code in the pastebin link in functions.php of your theme
http://pastebin.com/LA4zB4TF

In the js file of your theme, inside the document.ready function add the following jQuery function in pastebin link

http://pastebin.com/RTYX1Bik

Hope this works for you.

Comment: i can make a code like: echo "Hello world!<br>"; and it will show it. yet getting values from specific postmeta dosnt work :(

Comment: this code doesnt work. still new column values are blank