# Displaying shipping zip code in the "Orders" list on Admin -> Woocommerce -> Orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How can I display the shipping zip code associated to order in the “Orders” list view? Is there a hook that is available to include the shipping as an item in the individual order row?
Thank you.

```
//add a column
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION($columns){
    $new_columns = (is_array($columns)) ? $columns : array();
    unset( $new_columns['order_actions'] );

    //edit this for you column(s)
    //all of your columns will be added before the actions column
    $new_columns['MY_COLUMN_ID_1'] = 'Distro test';
    //stop editing

    $new_columns['order_actions'] = $columns['order_actions'];
    return $new_columns;
}
// add data to column
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION', 2 );
function MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION($column){
  // ***WHAT MUST I DO HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***
    //stop editing
}
// sort column
add_filter( "manage_edit-shop_order_sortable_columns", 'MY_COLUMNS_SORT_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_SORT_FUNCTION( $columns ) {
    $custom = array(
        //start editing

        'MY_COLUMN_ID_1'    => 'MY_COLUMN_1_POST_META_ID'
        //stop editing
    );
    return wp_parse_args( $custom, $columns );
}
```

Comment: The solution is given there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683162/woocommerce-show-custom-column Enjoy :)

Comment: Hi, i have seen that post. but i don't know how to call shipping zipcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and that work on the latest woocommerce version. The way to get order data changed since the link i sent you. So test this :

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION($columns){
$new_columns = (is_array($columns)) ? $columns : array();
unset( $new_columns['order_actions'] );

//edit this for you column(s)
//all of your columns will be added before the actions column
$new_columns['zip_code'] = 'Zip Code';
//stop editing

$new_columns['order_actions'] = $columns['order_actions'];
return $new_columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION',10,  2 );
function MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION($column){
global $post, $the_order;

if ( empty( $the_order ) || $the_order->id != $post->ID ) {
    $the_order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
}

//start editing, I was saving my fields for the orders as custom post meta
//if you did the same, follow this code
if ( $column == 'zip_code' ) {
    if(isset($the_order->shipping_postcode)): 
        $zip_code = $the_order->shipping_postcode;
        if($zip_code == 'california store zip code'):
            echo 'California';
        elseif($zip_code == 'other store zip code'):
            echo 'Other store location';
        else:
            echo $zip_code;
        endif;
    endif;
}
//stop editing
}
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot! it work! :). It save a lot of time of me. It take me a lot of time with google.
Can i check this zip code, if it exist in a table of my database. will echo "California"?
Because i have 2 store in different address. i think i should use $wpdb?

Comment: i updated the code, juste remplace california store zip code, other store zip code and Other store location ( for the name )

Comment: Hi, that isn't my mean.

Comment: hmmm... I have a table in my database.
if this zip code exist in my table -> echo 'California'
else echo 'North Carolina'.
i use this function:

Comment: if ( $column == 'zip_code' ) {
    $resultdistro= $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT zipcode FROM $wpdb->zipcodedistro1" );
     if($resultdistro) echo 'California'
     else echo 'North Carolina'
}
but i have 500 error.

Comment: isen't a good idea to do this. the zipcode california never change ? if not, change condition by this : if($zip_code == 'california store zip code'):
            echo 'California';
        else
            echo 'North Carolina';
        endif;

Comment: Hi, because my store have 2 address. i have a snippet code to chose near store. now i need to show which store with order.
store 1 in california.
store 2 in north carolina.
And i created 2 table with data as zip codes will sell by store 1 and zip codes will sell by store 2.
So i need to display which store in my admin page. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062495/how-to-check-variable-exist-in-database-wordpress-using-wpdb