# How to check variable exist in database wordpress using $wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In Function.php, I want to check if my variable exist in a table of wordpress database, but it don't work.

```
global $wpdb;
    $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->pincode_distro1 WHERE pincode = $the_order->shipping_postcode"));
    if($count == 1) { echo 'distro 1'}
    else { echo 'distro 2'}
```

Comment: Doesn't work *how*, aside from the obvious syntax-error.

Comment: @1way 
thanks for your help before. Please help me see this problem

Comment: Hi Qirel, Can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: I think i got a syntax-error. because when i save functions.php. i got 500 error

Comment: Yeah, you do have one - and the highlighting here makes it quite obvious. (Hint: Missing `"` at the end of your query). And you should always get the actual error, [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: Hi, i have put " in my code. but it don't work.

Comment: Like I said, get the *actual* error-message by applying [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file. And beside, "*does not work*" isn't descriptive at all, doesn't really help us much.

Comment: Hi, thank you Qirel. It work. But the result not right. All results is distro 2. Is there any problem here? i just want check exist of $the_order->shipping_postcode in my table.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($count);` and check what it actually contains.

Comment: **WARNING**: You've created a dangerous [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) by putting user data directly in your query. **NEVER** do this. Instead, use the WordPress [prepared statements feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to properly escape all data parameters.

Comment: Hi @Qirel i got NULL for all.

Comment: Thanks tadman. i want it work first, i will check it later.

Comment: I have check with this code:
    global $wpdb;
       `$count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb-    >pincode_distro1");
    var_dump($count);
but always get NULL result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you won't need $wpdb->prepare() for that, tried this way?

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->pincode_distro1 WHERE pincode = '$the_order->shipping_postcode'");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it give me NULL for all result.

Answer (score 2):

remove `$wpdb` from table name . Code will work

from

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->pincode_distro1 WHERE pincode = '$the_order->shipping_postcode'");
```

to

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pincode_distro1 WHERE pincode = '$the_order->shipping_postcode'");
```