# How to create a custom datepicker field product in backend?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to add date picker custom filed individual product in backend and that filed save in database also so please give me suggestion for that as soon as possible.

Comment: Possible it will help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595054/7155723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin for creating datepicker custom field in products section

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-custom-product-data-fields/

And if you want to display other custom fields without plugin then use this documentation

http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/

```
    Hello Vishit Following code will display content of post meta in template file or anywhere where you want to display For Example :

    <?php if ($company_v=get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'company_v', true ) ) :  ?>
  <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i><span>
<?php if($company_v) { echo $company_v; } ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can You please write code in which code i wirte in functions file for date picker i cant understand.

Comment: Hello Vishit first one is plugin and second link is for custom fields other than datepicker

Comment: For Datepicker you can use plugin and other fields you have to make functions in functions.php and you can use it in woocommerce default files

Comment: But i am using plugin for date picker but how can i display date picker in product page ?

Comment: Custom data filed not display in particular product tab.. Check Screen shot https://ps.w.org/woocommerce-custom-product-data-fields/assets/screenshot-1.png?rev=1329070

Comment: I have given code for getting post meta in template file or anywhere you want to display the content

Comment: Can you please write the code post meta i added in template file but does not display.

Comment: Above code not working.. and i also check in data base meta value display wc_productdata_options this and that value display in array but i wanted to display only value not in array.

Comment: can you show me your code for displaying custom meta what you have written in template?

Comment: echo $company_v=get_post_meta( '54', 'mydatepicker_1', true );
template file display black.

Comment: Function.php file code : 
array(
             'id'          => '_mydatepicker_1',
             'type'        => 'datepicker',
             'label'       => __('Select date', 'wc_cpdf'),
             'placeholder' => __('A placeholder text goes here.', 'wc_cpdf'),
             'class'       => 'large',
             'description' => __('Field description.', 'wc_cpdf'),
             'desc_tip'    => true,
       )

Comment: and what is the code which you kept in template ? for post meta